# Success criteria on InvokeRESTAPI task throwing exception

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On my `InvokeRESTAPI` task I have opted to use the `successCriteria` option as follows:

`successCriteria: eq(root["status"], "successful")`

It does not seem to be correct and for the response shown, it throws an exception.

```
   Response Code: OK
                    Response: {
      "action": "...",
      "status": "successful"
    }
                    Evaluation of expression 'eq(root["status"], "successful")' failed.
                    
    Exception Message: Unrecognized value: '"status"'. Located at position 9 within expression: eq(root["status"], "successful").
```

I found it a bit hard to understand the little information available on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/servertaskauthoring.md). How should I properly parse the response to my rest API invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single quotes to replace double quotes.

For example:

```
eq(root['status'], 'successful')
```

Then it will work.

[image]